# To make threads sleep in parallel, each with random amount of time

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a set of threads, out of which I want "count" number of threads to go to sleep in parallel but wake up after random amount of time(stored in delay for that person). This code does this thing in sequential order.

```
Map<Thread,Person> threads=utils.getAllThreads();
Set<Thread> th=threads.keySet();
int count =5; //no of threads that go to sleep
System.out.println("count"+count);
Iterator it=th.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
    if(count==0) 
        break;

Thread t=(Thread) it.next();
try{
    t.suspend();
    System.out.println(((Person)threads.get(t)).getName()+"  is offline");

    Thread.sleep(((Person)threads.get(t)).getDelayOffline());

   //after sometime resume it

   count--;
   t.resume();
   System.out.println(((Person)threads.get(t)).getName()+"  back online");
 }

catch(Exception ex){

}
```

So, I want

1. count number of threads to go to sleep in parallel and wake up after random amount of time.
2. Is there any way to shuffle Set? so, that every time different threads go to sleep.

Comment: you cannot shuffle a set since it is unordered (e. g. `HashSet`) or have defined order which cannot be changed (e. g. `TreeSet`), use `List` instead

Comment: BTW, `Thread#suspend()` and `Thread#resume()` are deprecated.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou i agree that the two are deprecated but In my code usage, before the threads start anything, I am making them sleep(to replicate behaviour of offline user). So suspend and resume may not cause any problem as per my knowledge(like deadlock etc.) since they do not start at all. Thanks for the reply for set part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First of all, I would seriously reconsider the use of 'suspend' **, it's a recipe for trouble especially if your threads hold locks.

If you need 'suspend' anyway, you might just use java.util.Timer and schedule task(s) to wake up the threads.

```
    Timer timer=new Timer();

    // for each thread 't':
    t.suspend();
    final Thread tFinal=t;  
   // just a shortcut to allow my TimerTask to access 't' (alternatively you can 
   // have an explicit constructor for your TimerTask, and pass 't' to it)
    timer.schedule(
            new TimerTask() {
                @Override public void run() {
                    tFinal.resume();
                }
            }, 
            YOUR_RANDOM_VALUE);
```

Obviously there are variations, e.g. you you have many threads that repeatedly need to be suspended and resumed all the time, you might also have a single TimerTask that executes every, say, 30 seconds, and resumes all threads that are eligible (assuming your sleep time is much higher than 30 secs - say whole minutes - so you can live with an error margin of 30).

Comment: Hi, This worked for me. Thanks a lot. I was not aware of the timer, this was actually what I wanted to do.

Comment: Glad to hear :)  Still could I kindly ask whether you really need 'suspend'? I haven't seen it in production code for years... obviously feel free to ignore if you know what you're doing and don't want to be nagged about it :)

Comment: Actually I am trying to replicate behavior of an offline user, user is initially ofline and wakes up after random amount of time, so threads do not hold any monitors, hence suspend may not create any problem, I assume.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `shuffle` method which is supported for collections which extend `List` and it does not apply for Set. But if you still want to do it then you can use the following code:

```
Map<Thread,Person> threads=utils.getAllThreads();
Set<Thread> th=threads.keySet();
List<Thread> list = new ArrayList<Thread>(th);
Collections.shuffle(list);
th.clear();
th.addAll(list);
```

This is going to be costly. Another option can be to generate some random numbers based on size of set and then select those items from set.

Comment: Yea, actually I am currently doing it with random numbers but was looking for a cleaner way for the same